# Joomla Module hidden from registered users

Tags: joomla, module, joomla3.0

I have a joomla 3.6.5 site with T3 and Bootstrap 3.
One of the menu items displays some info to registered users only.
If a user is not registered then a module ("public access") appears with "Registered Users Only" message and info.
But this module still appears to registered users (I guess because its access is "public").
I want to show this module to all users EXCEPT the registered ones but I couldnt find a way to do it so far.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: The following link explains it for an older version of Joomla. But Tested for Joomla 3.8 working.
[How do you hide something from logged in users?](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_hide_something_from_logged_in_users%3F)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far is to download the Advanced Module Manager,
and then assign an exclusion of a user group to the module.
If anyone knows of an easier way without using any plugins please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the user group as GUEST and try